# Ramanujan's series for the exponential integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Convergent_series), Ramanujan came up with the following series expansion of the exponential integral:

$$\operatorname{Ei}(x)=\gamma+\ln|x|+e^{x/2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n!2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}\frac1{2k+1}$$

My first instinct was to try and verify the derivative:

$$\frac{e^x}x\stackrel?=\frac1x+\frac12e^{x/2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^n}{n!2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}\frac1{2k+1}\right)+e^{x/2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac1{2k+1}\right)$$

and then perhaps apply Cauchy products? If so, then this doesn't seem very nice at all.

How can I show this equality?

---

Also as an aside, but below the formula on Wikipedia are some claimed bounds, which no matter how I look at it, are wrong, or if perhaps a typo, what should they be?

Comment: $f(x) =e^{-x/2} (E_i(x)-\log x - \gamma),-\frac12 e^{x/2} f(x)+e^{x/2}f'(x) =\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}$, $f(x) = \sum_{n \ge 0} c_n x^n$ and you can check your formula for $c_n$ fits into that equation, it is order 1 linear ODE so the solution space is your particular solution plus the one dimensional space of the homogeneous equation $-g/2+g'=0$ and comparing the first few coefficients indicates you found the correct one

Comment: Have a look at this very recent paper : https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01847480/document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subtract $\frac{1}{x}$ and multiply by $xe^{-x/2}$ to avoid the Cauchy product and instead use the known series expansions of $e^x$. You would get $$e^{x/2} -e^{-x/2} \stackrel?= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{n+1}}{n!2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}\frac1{2k+1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n!2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac1{2k+1}$$

Write out the series expansion of the left hand side to get $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{2^n n!} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{2^n n!} \stackrel?= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{n+1}}{n!2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}\frac1{2k+1} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{n+1}}{n!2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac1{2k+1}$$

From here, you can just show that the $x^n$ terms are the same on both sides. It's clearly equal for $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ ($[x^0] = 0$ and $[x^1] = 1$). Other than that, you would need to show the relation $$\frac{1}{2^n n!} - \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n n!} \stackrel?= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-2}}{\left(n-1\right)!2^{n-2}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-2)/2 \rfloor}\frac{1}{2k+1}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(n-1\right)!2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}\frac{1}{2k+1}$$

Multiplying by $2^n n!$ and factoring the RHS, this simplifies to $$1 - (-1)^n \stackrel?= 2n\left(-1\right)^{n}\left( \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-2)/2 \rfloor}\frac{1}{2k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor}\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)$$

Splitting this up into even and odd cases makes it easier. If $n$ is even, then the LHS is  $0$ and $\lfloor (n-2)/2 \rfloor = \lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor$, so the RHS is $0$ as well. If $n$ is odd, then the LHS is $2$. The RHS would be $$-2n\left( -\frac{1}{2\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor + 1} \right) = -2n \cdot \frac{-1}{n} = 2$$

Therefore, the left hand side and the right hand side are both equal.

Comment: And now I wonder how Ramanujan came up with it in the first place, but that's true for most of Ramanujan's things :P